# Определение страны клиента

Tags: локализация, php

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки :)
У меня вопрос: хочу сделать на странице так, чтобы при заходе на нее автоматически определялась страна клиента. Далее после определения грузится язык итальянский, если Италия, русский для СНГ и России и английский если другая какая-то.
Как лучше и правильней сделать определение страны ?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понял, изначальный вопрос - как определить язык, а не страну. Можно сразу определять языки, которые пользователь хотел бы получить - смотреть [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
```

Получится что-то вроде "`ru,uk;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4`", где `q` - приоритет языка, выставленный пользователем. Удобнее это выглядит после разбора:

```
array (size=4)
  'ru' => int 1
  'uk' => string '0.8' (length=3)
  'en' => string '0.6' (length=3)
  'en-US' => string '0.4' (length=3)
```

Таким образом, я бы хотел получить ответ на русском, если нет такого, то на украинском и т.д.

Плюс в том, что пользователь сам решает какой язык ему ближе, независимо от его местоположения или того, что прописано в базах ip-адресов.

Как распарсить можно узнать тут: [Parse Accept-Language to detect a user's language](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header).

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Вы меня правильно поняли :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот, думаю, эти статьи могут вам помочь

- [`Sypex Geo` — быстрое определение города по IP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146597/)
- [Определение вхождения `IP` адреса в диапазон](http://habrahabr.ru/post/138297/)

Comment: Вторая ссылка не совсем в тему- она про алгоритм ускорения определения вхождения IP адреса в диапазон IP адресов в базе данных MyISAM.